# How to keep StackPanel up, when resizing window?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

I would like that when I minimize the window, the StackPanel stays on its position (Stay on top, don't go under) while the window is minimized.

***I'm not looking for a direct answer, I just want to find some direction, some help on where to start.***

#### Problem (GIF Format)

[GIF Of The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB7Od.gif)

#### XAML Code

```
<Grid Padding="25">
    <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Top">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Test" IsSelected="False" Icon="PreviewLink" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1111">
            <StackPanel Width="1400" Height="1000" Margin="85, 0, 0, 150">

                <Border CornerRadius="25" Background="#1D1D1D" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="-1099, 50, 10, 10">

                    <Canvas Background="#1D1D1D" Width="250" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="40" Padding="0, 35, 300, 0" Margin="115, 35, 0, 0" Text="Test"
                                   Foreground="#1D1D1D"
                                    />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>

                <Border CornerRadius="25" Background="#1D1D1D" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="-420, -190, 10, 10">


                    <Canvas Opacity="50" Background="#1D1D1D" Width="250" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="40" Padding="0, 35, 300, 0" Margin="115, 35, 0, 0" Text="Test"
                                   Foreground="#1D1D1D"
                                    />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>


                <Border CornerRadius="25" Background="#1D1D1D" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="260, -190, 10, 10">

                    <Canvas Background="#1D1D1D" Width="250" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="40" Padding="0, 35, 300, 0" Margin="115, 35, 0, 0" Text="Test"
                                   Foreground="#1D1D1D"
                                    />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>


                <Border CornerRadius="25" Background="#1D1D1D" Height="180" Width="300" Margin="940, -190, 10, 10">

                    <Canvas Background="#1D1D1D" Width="250" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Padding="0, 35, 300, 0" Margin="60, 35, 0, 0" Text="Test"
                                   Foreground="#1D1D1D"
                                    />
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>

    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The settings may need to be made for a ViewBox that has a Uniform stretch. Is it not enough to set VerticalAlignment = "Top" (for ViewBox)?

Comment: That's strange, now it works, before it didn't. Maybe I have something mixed up. You have officially solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the StackPanel stays on its position (Stay on top, don't go under) while the window is minimized.

The problem looks [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-22621) auto resize cause, you could try to set `Stretch` property as `Fill` to make StackPanel stays on the top, but it will make `Canvas` item shape change when resize the window.

The other way is fix ViewBox on the top of parent container by setting up `VerticalAlignment` as top.